# Stamp Duty for EU citizens (UK residents)

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, property-taxes

I am about to purchase as house which costs less than 400k in the UK under a leasehold over 110 years. Currently, they say there are no stamp duty rates applying until the end of June 2021. The house is going to be my main residence (flat to live in) and not a buy to let or an alternative place to live (e.g holidays etc). My main residence at the moment is a flat I am renting privately from a landlord.

I am a bit confused as I am aware that I have share of ownership in some cases and a flat for which my grandmother owns the usufruct. All those are based in South Europe (EU).

A solicitor told me that I would have to pay 12k approximately.

Just to recap in bullets:

1. The new house is going to be my main residence
2. My current residence is a house I am renting
3. I am a UK resident who is going to be a UK citizen soon as the
   ceremony is pending
4. The new flat is going to be acquired before the end of June
5. According the gov page, this should be my answer as I am replacing my current main residence (where I rent though a private landlord):
   [image]

Does anyone have experience on this matter?

Answer (score 3):

You’re not replacing your main residence, because your current main residence is rented not owned. And your part-ownership of other properties does mean that you’re liable for the extra 3% — it doesn’t matter that they’re not in the UK.

Note also that unless you’re already pretty far along, you’re unlikely to be able to complete the purchase by 30 June, so you’ll only benefit from the £250,000 nil-rate band that’s lasting until 30 September, and have £7,500 (5% of £150K) to pay on a £400K purchase as well as the £12K for the 3% second home surcharge. Leasehold purchases with a mortgage typically take four months from agreeing the purchase with the seller to completion, and things are going slower than normal at present since there are so many people trying to beat the deadline.

Comment: I agree, you are liable for the stamp duty on an "additional property". There's a good calculator here: https://www.stampdutycalculator.org.uk/stamp-duty-holiday.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. I lost any hope. Our rights are gone and it is devastating. 12k for a tax even with a discount is excessive. The only way is to give the current property to a family member. Or open a business and buy it under the corporate name? Is that possible? But in that case, help to buy will not count, I guess.

Comment: @Datacrawler In fact, 3% is pretty cheap by European standards. It’s 8% to 10% in Spain, 5% in France, 3.5% to 6.5% in Germany.

Comment: In Spain you can get a mansion with 130000 euros where in the UK, an equivalent house would cost 817000 euros. As a result, the taxes overall are still cheaper in Spain etc.

Comment: Why do you say "Our rights are gone and it is devastating."? Paying stamp duty is a normal part of a property transaction in the UK. It's no different than walking into a shop and complaining that you had to pay VAT on your purchases. If you can't afford the property+stamp duty then you have to buy a cheaper property. Sorry if this sounds harsh but I don't understand the issue.

Comment: @Vicky Agreed. While there are a lot of things you can put down to Brexit, this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Vicky I am a US citizen; I'm also surprised by the comment about rights being gone. We don't call it a stamp tax, but we have something similar. If one partly or wholly owns a home, and buys a 2nd home, the tax treatment is more punitive. I don't even know if there is a grace period. Also, If one sells one's primary residence, one has up to 3 years to purchase another primary residence. Otherwise, the profit on the sale of the home is taxed at 26% (or if sold at a loss, the 26% capital tax deduction of the amount of the loss is forfeited.)